# Class constants without naming collision

Tags: objective-c, class, constants, collision, naming

I have seen many answers to define constants just by using `extern int const Something` in .h file and `int const Something = 1` in .m file.

But the problem is - these are not class constants and I cannot use them with . notation or use some other mechanism to differentiate the owning class.

For example,

ClassA.h

```
extern int const SomeErrorCode;
```

ClassB.h

```
extern int const SomeErrorCode;
```

and then I have ClassC.m where I want to use both ClassA and ClassB and check their method error codes:

```
#import <ClassA.h>
#import <ClassB.h>

@implementation ClassC

-(void)doIt
{
     ClassA * objA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
     ClassB * objB = [[ClassB alloc] init];

     int resultA = [objA doSomething];
     // how do I check for resultA == ClassA.SomeErrorCode ?

     int resultB = [objB doSomething];
     // how do I check for resultB == ClassB.SomeErrorCode ?
}

@end
```

How do I ensure that I can use both classes and have no collisions for ClassA.SomeErrorCode and ClassB.SomeErrorCode in case they have different values?

Comment: When I use `extern`, I use prefix (like doing when I create classes), and give a name linking them to the class where they are defined, and use "k", if the are const, and not if they are static. Like `extern int const kAFMyClassAErrorCode`

Comment: Did you ever wonder why they are constants named `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` and not `TextDidChange`?

Comment: Yes, and this made me think "yack, Objective-C is messy". I guess I'll have to get used to it then, if there are no other cleaner options.

Comment: It's not "messy", Objective-C and its "rules" is quite "verbose", that's just a habit. Also, naming methods, var is not something to take lightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to reference the constants outside the file where they're defined, then don't declare them in your .h files. Without those declarations they won't be seen by the linker, and there'll be no name collisions.

If you do need the constants to be visible in other modules, you'll need to make up names for them that are globally unique.